# "input string was not in a correct format " RFID card reading through usb

Tags: c#, string, input, rfid

I am trying to get the string value of an RFID card using C#. When I pass the 1st value, at the start of the string I get a symbol which I cannot identify. When I pass more values, the symbol changes.

I want to convert this string into integer value for further process. When I do that I am getting the error

> Input string was not in correct format

I think the unidentified symbol that's preventing me from making this conversion.

Here is my code:

```
this.textBox1.Text = data;
x = Int32.Parse(data, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

and also help me to show this x value in a separate textbox.

[image: unidentified symbol image is here]

Comment: Is that symbol not in some way important?

Comment: No, I don't want that symbol. I could not convert the value from hex to int. I am thinking that the symbol may be causing this conversion issue.

Answer (score 0):

"and also help me to show this x value in a separate textbox."
I guess you could create a new TextBox and give it the value of x like:

```
TextBox textBox2 = new TextBox();
textBox2.Text = "This is the content of x: " + x;
textBox2.Show(); //Or textBox2.Visible = true;
```

I'm not quite sure about how to arrange the textbox since I've just used the GUI designer of VS so far, sorry mate. You could also create a textbox in the GUI Designer make it's visibility on false, until you gave the textbox the value of x and then set it's visibility on true again ;).

Have you tried Convert.ToInt32(yourInput); instead of Parse? I'm also a beginner in C# but maybe the parsing creates the unknown Letter?
I hope I was able to help you at least a bit, wish you a nice day and good luck! :-)

Comment: Even before converting the value, i get that symbol while displaying the read value itself. after that only I am trying to convert it from hex to int.

Comment: You could also try to use x = x.Remove(0,1); If I'm not wrong this should always remove the first character of your string. Does this help?